# Parity 1.7 [-32601] Method not found CLOSE

Tags: ether, parity, parity-wallet

I just upgraded Parity to 1.7.
The syncing with the Foundation chain has not completed.
I decided to create a new Account while the syncing was happening.
I am using the browser interface.

Everything went until it asked for the owner recovery phrase. I carefully entered this phrase. Clicked the create button. Received this error:

> [-32601] Method not found CLOSE

I tried re-entering the owner recovery phrase. It still doesn't work. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Update:
Cross posted [on github](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/6285).

Comment: Could you report this at Github? Sounds like quite some critical issue.